# Listing PDF files in dir with PHP 7.2

Tags: php, pdf, file-get-contents, php-7.2, opendir

The function below lists all PDF files in choosen directory. Also reads and print out the song title inside the PDF (they are all songs). The script works like a charm in PHP 5.6 but not in PHP 7.2. I have to upgrade to 7.2 because of my hosting company.

```
function listPDF($dirtoread) {

if($handle = opendir("pdf/".$dirtoread)) {

//ny
$theFiles = array();

$count = 0;
while($currentfile = readdir($handle)) {

    if(!ereg('^\.',$currentfile)) {
        $theFiles[$count] = $currentfile;
        $count++;
    }
}

sort($theFiles,SORT_STRING);

for ($i=0; $i < count($theFiles); $i++){

        $string = file_get_contents("pdf/".$dirtoread."/".$theFiles[$i]);
        $start = strpos($string, "<dc:title>") + 10;
        $length = strpos(substr($string, $start), '</dc:title>');

        if ($length) {
            $title = strip_tags(substr($string, $start, $length));
        }


        echo "<a  class='popup gallery pdf' rel='width:700;height:600'  href='pdf/".$dirtoread."/".$theFiles[$i]."' style='text-decoration:none; line-height:2em;'><img src='pdf/pdf_small.gif' align='bottom' border='0'> ".$title."</a><br>";


}
closedir($handle);
}
}
```

Comment: Define "not working". Do you get any error?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! Found it. Ereg function deprecated in php 7...

Comment: you should have look on `glob` function who do the job for you